# Socket data not getting received when the request is made from a raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to send and receive data from a server. When I run the below python program from eclipse or python IDLE I get the response from the server. But, when I run the program from Raspberry Pi I am getting an error. Below is the simple code and error.

```
import socket,time
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1883
address = (ip,port)
client.connect(address)
print("connected")

def close():
    global client
    client.close()
    client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(address)


while 1:
    client.send(b'\x01\x04\x00\x00\xxxxxx')
    print("sent")
    try:
        raw_data = client.recv(1024)
    except:
        close()
        raw_data = client.recv(1024)
    received_data = " ".join("{:02x}".format(byte) for byte in 
    (raw_data))
    print(received_data)
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run this code in raspberry pi,I get BrokenPipe error. why it is happening in raspberry pi?

Error:

```
connected
sent
received

sent

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "exdu.py", line 18, in <module>
    client.send(b'\x01\x04\x00\x00\xxxxxxxxx')
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: You are trying to receive something from the client (try block) and if it fails (except block) you are trying it again. What if it fails in the except block? You are no longer catching that exception

Comment: I have the socket error exceptions, I have not added to this code. But, the above code used to get the response when it is executed from python IDLE, I am not sure what is actually happening with the raspberry pi.

Comment: Post the full traceback. At which line is the exception raised? Also catch and print the exception in the `except:` clause. In the failure case, is the data successfully sent from the client and can you confirm its receipt by the server? Broken pipe generally means writing to a closed connection, so the server is closing the connection... the traceback could help to figure out where that's happening and why.

Comment: I see you setting up a client to connect to a server on the local machine. Might be a stupid question, but is the server (assuming MQTT, based on the port number) actually running on the RasPi when you attempt to execute this script there (or, do you replace the `ip` in the script accordingly)?

Comment: @mhawke, I tried with one of your solutions on some other post related to the Broken pipe, I was getting the same error. please refer the updated question. But couldn't figure out a solution for this

Comment: @shmee, My server is not on RasPI, my client is

Answer (score 0):

A broken pipe is caused when a pipe (in this case a TCP socket) is closed unexpectedly by the other side and `recv` gets back an empty response or `send` tries to write to a closed connection.

There are quite a couple pieces of not so best practice code may be causing a broken pipe error in your code.

I'll try and point out a few things that stand out to me using comments:

```
import socket,time
# it would be nice to have a function wrapping this but as it is this is not the issue.
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1883
address = (ip,port)
client.connect(address)
print("connected")

def close():
    global client
    # If you read the python socket documentation https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html
    # you will see that they advise sending a shutdown packet to the other side of the connection.
    # In my experience this is actually extremely important when properly handling TCP connections and may be causing this issue.
    # you must do this from the side that closes the connection, this includes when the server closes a connection.
    client.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR) # this is what you want to do here.
    client.close()
    # connecting to a new socket here makes no sense and may also cause an issue.
    client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(address)
    raw_data=client.recv(1024)


while 1:
    client.send(b'\x01\x04\x00\x00\xxxxxx')
    print("sent")
    try:
        raw_data = client.recv(1024)
    except:
        # this except statement may cause an exception itself.
        # Not only that but you are probably getting your broken pipe error
        # here from the recv in close().
        close()
        raw_data = client.recv(1024)
    received_data = " ".join("{:02x}".format(byte) for byte in 
    (raw_data))
    print(received_data)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Apologies for the code comments, but i find they're useful when the segment is copy pasted when you are trying to experiment with a solution.

As an extension i would write the code you have to be much more like the python docs example:

```
class mysocket:
    def __init__(self, sock=None):
        if sock is None:
            self.sock = socket.socket(
                socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        else:
            self.sock = sock

    def connect(self, host, port):
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

    # important bit of missing code
    def disconnect(self):
        self.sock.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
        self.sock.close()

    def mysend(self, msg):
        totalsent = 0
        while totalsent < MSGLEN:
            sent = self.sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
            if sent == 0:
                raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
            totalsent = totalsent + sent

    def myreceive(self):
        chunks = []
        bytes_recd = 0
        while bytes_recd < MSGLEN:
            chunk = self.sock.recv(min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, 2048))
            if chunk == '':
                raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
            chunks.append(chunk)
            bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)
        return ''.join(chunks)
```

You can rewrite the send and recieve functions to do your bidding and then call it like:

```
socket = mysocket()
socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 1883)
try:
    socket.mysend(b'\x01\x04\x00\x00\xxxxxx')
    raw_data = socket.myrecieve()
    # do more stuff
except:
    socket.disconnect()
```

This is example code but may set you on the right path.

Answer (score -1):

Broken pipe implies something isn't going through exactly as you want it to. Are you sure the server is running correctly on the raspberry pi on `localhost`?

Otherwise you might want to either run the server seperately(maybe heroku or digitalocean is relevant) or check your pi's firewall(I highly doubt this is the problem for localhost -> localhost connections)

Comment: My server is somewhere else, I am trying to connect with my server using my client program in my machine(ie, raspberry pi). I am sure my server is running as expected. Otherwise, I won't receive the response when I run the program in python IDLE from my local machine.